# Not able to send HTML mail contents through command line in nodejs

Tags: node.js, email, command-line

Not able to get mail by below command:

```
cmd = ` ( echo -e "${message}" ) | mail -r "from me-<\`whoami\`@\`hostname\`>" \
    -a "From: me@example.com" \
    -a "MIME-Version: 1.0" \
    -a "Content-Type: text/html" \
    -s "${subject}" ${address}`

where message=`<html>
            <head><title></title></head>
            <body>\nHi, \\n
            <p>
            <a href='test'>Approve</a>\\n</p></body></html>`,
```

Please suggest changes in this. Thanks!!!